# Managed Clients on OS X

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, mac

Is there an easy way to tell if a Mac is being managed by an OS X server system, and what settings are being changed (or cached) if it is being managed by an OS X server system, to make sure client notebooks are getting the proper settings from our server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways.

1. Go to the Apple Menu -> About This Mac -> More Info (or just run System Profiler directly).  Under the "Software" disclosure triangle is a setting called "Managed Client".  If any settings are being managed, they will show up here.
2. Run `mcxquery` in the Terminal.  If you are a managed user, that'll be enough.  You can also specify flags that will have it check as though you were a different user or using a different machine.

Note that these tools [may give you different results](https://serverfault.com/questions/72578/why-do-mcxquery-and-system-profiler-sometimes-give-different-results).

Comment: You are quite welcome.